# Ruby on Rails rspec bug?

Tags: ruby, rspec

every time i execute rspec, dosen't matter what I have done, if the code is wrong it tells:

```
nev3rkill@nev3rkill-virtual-machine ~/Documentos/ruby $ rspec 
/home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load': no such file to load -- /home/nev3rkill/Documentos/ruby/spec (LoadError)
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/nev3rkill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
nev3rkill@nev3rkill-virtual-machine ~/Documentos/ruby $
```

I have tested with a lot of versions, with ruby 1.9.3,1.9.2 but i don't know. Is it normal?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're in a path with a `spec` directory (e.g. the root of your rails project), you also need to tell `rspec` which spec files to run, either by passing it a directory or file. e.g:

```
$ rspec path/to/specs/
```

Will run all the specs in the `path/to/specs/` path (recursively), or:

```
$ rspec spec/your_specs.rb
```

will run the specs in the `spec/your_specs.rb` file.

Comment: as of rspec-2.7 you can just type `rspec` and it will load the spec directory if there is one, but there has to be one. My guess is that @Rob Davis is typing `rspec` in a directory that is not a project directory. Rob Davis, pls confirm.

Comment: @David Chelimsky: Thanks, I only noticed that after posting. I've amended my answer a bit.

Comment: I know how can I use rspec, and if I use rspec with a file that is OK, nothing wrong happens. The problem is when I use rspec in a file that has a bug or something wrong, then rspec shows the error but then too show all that crap of "from *****" that seems all internal errors of rspec.

Comment: @David Chelimsky, just to clarify: I corrected the title of this question when I came acros it (changed "respec" to "rspec", IIRC), but the question isn't mine. It's user1308906's. This is a somewhat confusing aspect of Stack Overflow's UI.